# mystery username with hg convert

Tags: python, svn, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I have a cloned mercurial repository, and a checked out subversion repository.

When I checkout the subversion repo I take the option to save my password as plain text.

I want import the mercurial repo into subversion, so I use mercurial's convert extension.

```
hg convert --debug --dest-type svn hgrepo svnrepo
```

Everything looks fine until the first commit:

```
Password for '"Michael':
```

It stops and asks for a password to correspond to username "Michael, but my username is michael.

Could anyone one tell me where it is pulling this username from, or how I could override it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check your ~/.hgrc file or .hg/hgrc file  the second one should be in the repo, the first one in your home directory.  These files are what mercurial reads for configuration and user information.

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html

Comment: Afraid not, there is nothing like that in the hgrc file, just my mercurial username.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the mercurial.ini

```
[ui]
username=Xyz
```